# Интерактивные Графики в Python: как реализовать аналог функции Manipulate из Mathematica

Tags: python, математика, график, численные-методы, mathematica

Добрый день! Недавно начал изучать Python, решая задачу по численным методам. Хотел узнать, можно ли как-то в Python реализовать аналог функции Manipulate как в Mathematica, чтобы была возможность варьировать данные, чтобы это было видно на графике. Привел скрин ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду рад любой помощи и подсказке. Спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697259/interactive-matplotlib-plot-with-two-sliders

Comment: вот документация и пример:
https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html
и про сам слайдер:
https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [`ipywidgets.interact` (чтобы ползунки/график появились, ячейку возможно пару раз исполнить нужно)](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/zed/jupyter-notebooks/master?filepath=ipynb%2FInteractive%20plot%20with%20two%20sliders.ipynb):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from ipywidgets import interact

def f(a, k):
    x = np.arange(11)
    plt.plot(x, x**k - 1)
    plt.plot(x, a * (x - 1))

interact(f, a=(0,5), k=(0,6))
```

[image: interactive plot with two sliders]

Можно записать этот код, используя синтаксис для аннотаций и декоратора:

```
@interact
def f(a: (0,5), k: (0,6)):
    x = np.arange(11)
    plt.plot(x, x**k - 1)
    plt.plot(x, a * (x - 1))
```

Comment: Почему-то не рисуется график( В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ползунки отображаются, а вот график нет. выдает: <function_main_.f>

Comment: @khammisha: выполните ячейку два раза как в ответе сказано. `__main__.f` это ожидаемо, так как `interact()` это декоратор.